# How to replace the contents of a div with content from another html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with three divs: container, side-nav, content.
I want to replace the HTML in the ***body*** div with the HTML in another (source) HTML file when I click a link in the side-nav.

index.html

```
<div class="float-container">
   <div class="sidenav">
     <a href="#about">About</a>
     <a href="#services">Services</a>
     <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
   </div>

   <div class="body">
      <p>some text here.</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

about.html

```
<h1>About Me</h1>
<p> yada yada yada</p>
```

Comment: use a server that has html templating

Comment: If you're learning HTML, I'd recommend you start by having four complete pages, **index.html**, **about.html**, **services.html** and **clients.html**. Repeat the menu in every page, and just link each item in the menu directly to the corresponding page, for example `<a href="about.html">About</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

The achieve this, use an `<iframe>`. HTML files can be directly loaded into iframes using the **src** attribute.

```js
const ibody = document.querySelector('iframe.body')
document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav>a').forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    ibody.src = a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() + '.html'
    console.log('loaded ' + ibody.src + ' into iframe')
  })
})
```

```css
.float-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
}

.sidenav {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sidenav a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">
   <div class="sidenav">
     <a>About</a>
     <a>Services</a>
     <a>Clients</a>
   </div>

   <iframe class="body" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does the code in the first snippet go?  <script>?

Comment: Yes, it is script.

Answer (score 0):

In simple way, I usually do it with **[frameset](https://codesandbox.io/s/frameset-qk09tx?file=/index.html)**.

[image]

Comment: `frameset` is deprecated ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset)).